# XText how to get EObjects from another plugin?

Tags: xtext, ecore

I started developing an XText DSL, which has now two sub-languages, which reference each other (to be more precise, A refers to B). They each have their own plugins, and generator workflow.

The relevant part of looks something like this:

**Language A:**

```
ARoot:
    'rootOfB:' (foos+=Foo)*;

Foo:
    'foo' name=ID;
```

**Language B:**

```
import 'url-of-a' as A

BRoot:
    'rootOfA:' (bars+=Bar)*;

Bar:
    'bar' name=ID 'for' foo=[A::Foo] ;
```

Now I try to provide a scope provider, so that in language B `foo` elements are recognized, but i did not find a way yet to get access to the parsed elements of A.
I did some debugging, and it looks like neither the parameter foo, nor the eReference has any kind of connection to the elements of language A:

```
class MyScopeProvider extends AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider {
    def IScope scope_Bar_foo(Bar bar, EReference eReference){
        // How should i reference and return all the Foo objects here?
    }
}
```

Foo elements also have a full-qualified name provider, so that shouldn't be a problem, i tested it from another scope, while still working on plugin A:

```
class MyQualifiedNameProvider extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {
    override qualifiedName(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Foo) {
            val f = o as Foo
            return QualifiedName.create(f.name)
        }
        super.qualifiedName(o);
    }
}
```

**So my question is**: How would i get the parsed EObjects in the a different plugin?

**Example usage:**

Contents of a file, that uses grammar A:

```
rootOfA
    foo firstFoo
    foo secondFoo
```

Contents of a file, that uses grammar B:

```
rootOfB
    bar firstBar for [i would like reference firstFoo or secondFoo here]
```

Comment: I tried your sample grammars and linking works when resources from languageA and languageB are in the same project, is that your case?
Also, if you press Ctrl + Shift + F3, can you see Foo item? how are they named?

Comment: No, the problem is they are in different projects (plugins). And from project B i try to access some model elements which are in project A. It should be possible, but i couldn't find a way to do it yet. When they were in the same project (and grammar) it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a dependency to plugin A in the Manifest of the plugin B.
You also have to add dependency into workflow mwe2.

See http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#grammarMixins for more details.

**Edit 1**

You are trying to make a reference to another resource. This article explains differences between local and global scope:
http://blogs.itemis.de/leipzig/archives/809

ScopeProvider does not apply here. You should implement your own ResourceDescriptionStrategy  for plugin A in order to describe what EObject you want to be exported from a resource A.
In your ScopeProvider (plugin B) you have to call delegateGetScope() to have global scope (A + B).

**Edit 2**

If you want to make linking work between two different project you can use the following Eclipse standard mechanism:

Right-click on project B and open *Properties*, and go to "Project Reference". You will see Project A, you just have to select it.

When it's done, clean your two projects and your linking will be ok.

**Edit 3**

Here an example of custom implementation for ResourceDescriptionStrategy:

```
public class MyResourceDescriptionStrategy extends DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean createEObjectDescriptions(EObject eObject,
            IAcceptor<IEObjectDescription> acceptor) {
        if (eObject instanceof Foo) {
            QualifiedName fullyQualifiedName = getQualifiedNameProvider().getFullyQualifiedName(eObject);
            IEObjectDescription ieObjectDescription = EObjectDescription.create(fullyQualifiedName, eObject);
            acceptor.accept(ieObjectDescription);
            return true;
        }
        return super.createEObjectDescriptions(eObject, acceptor);
    }
}
```

You have to bind this class in plugin A RuntimeModule:

```
public Class<? extends IDefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy> bindIDefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy() {
    return MyResourceDescriptionStrategy.class;
}
```

Here an example of ScopeProvider implementation using "global scope":

```
def IScope scope_Bar_foo(Bar bar, EReference eReference){
    return delegateGetScope(bar, eReference);
}
```

In this example, it will only search into global scope. If want to add something else to the scope you should use SimpleScope which can manage "parent scope".

Comment: I forgot to mention, i did both already. B depends on A, and A is present in B's workflow. I'm pretty sure, my configuration is and was correct. The thing I'm looking for, is  how i can access the ECore model of A in plugin B. Which class will provide the parsed model of A (which I need in B's scope provider)? I looked at `ECoreUtil`, and `ECoreUtil2` but I'm unsure, how it would be appropriate (and possible) to access A's root model. Look at `MyScopeProvider` in my question, and the comented part there please!

Comment: ScopeProvider is only used for local scope (inside the same resource), if you want to refer another resource the use case is global scope.

Comment: I never used/seen it. Could you provide some example, on how i could reference in `Bar.foo` all the `Foo` objects (which as you can see are part of another referenced grammar)?

Comment: I don't understand your use case, can you provide an example of files for languageA and languageB? And tell what exactly you are trying to solve?

Comment: Added an example in the question. Thank you for taking the time, and trying to help :)

Comment: If the resources are in differents projects you have to add visibility from one project to the other manually: see my edit 2.

Comment: Ok, so i looked into it, can you please provide an example (or link of an example) on what `ResourceDescriptionStrategy` is, and how should i use the delegated scope? I really didn't find anything (my version of xtext don't even have a class called `ResourceDescriptionStrategy`). By the way i read the blog post on itemis, it was really helpful in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: See my Edit 3. Let me now, if you have more questions.

Comment: This was really helpful, i still have some work to do, but i think you put me on the right track! Thank you!